# How to log detail after throwing an exception?

Tags: asp.net, exception

I'm pretty new to .net so my knowledge is pretty limited in many areas.

I'm creating a website at the moment, and have created a few static methods to help me out - here's an example:

```
    public static void ThrowNull<T>(this T obj, string param) where T : class
    {
        if (param.IsNullOrEmpty())
            Throw<ArgumentException>("Undefined param!");

        if (obj.IsNull())
            Throw<ArgumentNullException>(param);
    }
```

I use it as a parameter guard in other methods, calling like this: myVar.ThrowNull("myVar");

The Throw method referred to above looks like this:

```
    static void Throw<E>(string message) where E : Exception
    {
        throw Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(E), message) as E;
    }
```

This all works great for testing but I want to be able to log details that occur from users. How do I get stack trace information from this point?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: why can't u use logging framework ? Log4Net, ELMAH

Comment: I agree with Ravi, you should check Log4Net. It logs everything you want.

Comment: I don't know why this has been downvoted. It isn't a duplicate because I didn't ask how to perform error handling, I asked specifically how I got the stacktrace from the point in my code.

Comment: @Kami - I'll take a look at Log4Net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Exception newException = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(E), message) as E;
<Something?>newException.StackTrace
throw newException;
```

Comment: what does Something refer to?

Comment: Whatever it is you want to do with the stack trace... (which is a string btw)